# How can I get Google Analytics to report my semantic URL requests more accurately?

Tags: google-analytics

I have implemented "friendly" URLs, also called ["semantic" URLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL), on my website, using code similar to [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5595553/184108).

I've set it up so that the URL will direct to a specific name format so the right page will be retrieved. So if a user comes to the site by any of these links:

```
http://example.com/Some Crazy Page
http://example.com/SOME CRAZY PAGE
http://example.com/some%20crazy%20page
```

They will end up here:

```
http://example.com/some_crazy_page
```

The problem is that when my page redirects the user to the page with the right format, it essentially reloads the page as if it were a new HTTP request. This seems to make *Google Analytics* see each conversion as a new page visit. Which in turns mean that when I look at my *Google Analytics* data, I'm seeing thousands of hits on my website top page, displayed simply as `/` in the *Analytics* interface. It *looks* like my top page is by far the most popular page, when I know for sure that isn't the case.

**Is there a way I can get *Google Analytics* to filter out all these initial redirects?** I'm thinking something like "any time a user lands on `/` and the session is no longer than 1 second". Or if I could filter out all `301 permanently moved` redirects... Or maybe someone has a more clever solution.

My .htaccess file contains this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
```

My PHP code is complicated, so forgive me if I'm not including the right information, but it contains this (please let me know if there's more I should show):

```
public static function redirectURL ($articleName)
{
    header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header ('Location: ' . Session::getSession ()->encodeSessionID ($articleName));
    exit;
}
```